# Trouble using the package `fancyhdr`

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

I am trying to use the `fancyhdr` package, as per the title, to insert titles on the top right and top left of each page.

The problem is that I have titles that are too long to fit on one line and I would like somehow to reduce them.

Just to give an example, I have written the following sections:

```tex
\section{Lezione 1: Introduzione al corso e agli Algoritmi}
\newpage
\subsection{Cosa analizzeremo nel corso}:
```

The result I get is as follows:

[image]

This is what I've written so far:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %header e footer

%header/footer setup
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\small\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[L]{\small\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
%\fancyhead[L,R]{\small\thepage}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
%\lfoot{\authorName}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

% Da qui comincia la numerazione normale
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%\frenchspacing

% Da qui comincia la numerazione normale
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\cfoot{\thepage~di~\pageref{TotPages}}

\include{lezione1} 

\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can do the same thing, but just writing 'Lezione 1' instead of 'Lezione 1: Introduzione al corso e agli Algoritmi'?

**To explain**: I would like the section to (somehow) take the longer name, but in the `fancyhdr` to just say "Lezione 1" so that I get a result as follows.

`Table of content`

[image]

`fancyhdr`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You of course don't want headers for the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\fancypagestyle{normal}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{contents}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection. #1}}
% numbered sections
\titleformat{\section}
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {Lezione \thesection: }
% unnumbered sections
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {}

\newcommand{\lezione}[1]{%
  \section{#1}%
  \markboth{Lezione \thesection}{}%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{contents}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagestyle{normal}

\lezione{Introduzione al corso e agli algoritmi}

\lipsum

\subsection{Cosa analizzeremo nel corso}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Repeating ”1 Lezione 1” seems quite redundant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! thanks a lot.
Just one question: now the index title of the table of contents is preceded by "Lezione 0" is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: @LukeTheWolf I forgot to add the code for unnumbered sections. Fixed.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can update the `\sectionmark` that would otherwise be set automatically to include the ToC-related entry. Here's a minimal example in `article` that highlights the differences:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[ToC entry]{Title entry}
\sectionmark{Header entry}% Calls \markboth{<stuff>}{}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to include the sectional unit number (`\thesection` in the above case, which precedes `Header entry`) or even change the formatting, use `\markboth{HeaDeR eNTRy}{}` directly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It was just what I was looking for.
However, egreg's solution made me realise that I was putting some useless redundancy on my work. You still deserve my upvote!